# How can I permanently prevent Excel from setting all new documents to R1C1 mode?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Every time I create a new excel sheet, I have to go in and change it's cell reference mode to the familiar A1, B1, etc. I can't seem to find a way to permanently set it to A1 style.

Is there a macro I can write or a way to use templates or something, so that I don't have to keep changing the R1C1 setting?

Comment: You need to go to Tools>Options|General and uncheck the "R1C1 reference style".  Is this how you're doing it manually?

Comment: I would suggest that you stick with R1C1 as it makes debugging spreadsheets so much easier. Understanding what "=J4+1" means requires knowing your current cell, but "=RC[-1]+1" does not. Also copied formulas do not change when moving from cell to cell in R1C1, yet they do in A1, so spotting an error is much much easier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Office 2007, Click the Office button and click Excel Options which you will find at the end near Exit Excel.

Go to Formulas tab and under Working with formulas, Check or uncheck R1C1 reference style to use it or to change it to A1 reference style.

[image]
<sub>(source: [lytebyte.com](http://www.lytebyte.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/r1c1-reference-style-in-excel-2007.jpg))</sub>

If it doesn't stick you have some problem with a `personal.xls` or the default template or something I guess...

EDIT:

**Try this first:**
Close all spreadsheets down. Assuming you have created one previously, unhide your `Personal.xls` workbook (Window>Unhide; In Excel 2007 and newer,View,Unhide) and then uncheck the R1C1 reference style. Save your Personal.xls, rehide & close down Excel (clicking Yes to save changes to Personal.xls). With any luck you should now have your default A1 style back. You will have to repeat the above with any other workbooks in your XLSTART directory and/or the start up location in Tools>Options>General tab.

**Then this:**
Help > Detect & Repair.
If no good, try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291288

**Last resort:**
Use Start > Run `excel /regserver` 
NOTE the space after "excel"

Comment: It never sticks. Thats how I always changes it for a document

Comment: Unhiding and making the change in Personal.xls fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

You could create a toolbar button that allows you to change the worksheet to A1 type referencing. This Excel macro will do the job:

```
  Sub useA1references ()
      Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
  End Sub
```

If that works, you can set the macro to run whenever you [open Excel or create a new workbook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA010346281033.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, 
only [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2007/excel-keeps-unilaterally-changing-reference-style/e8716ca1-6ec3-4fb4-97fe-6463fa941cd2) worked (i paste the answer here, as it might go away):

> 1. Press [Alt]+[F11] to launch the VBE.
> 2. If the Immediate window isn't visible, press [Ctrl]+g.
> 3. In the Immediate window, type ? application.StartupPath and press Enter. VBA will display the path to XLStart.
> 4. Make a note of the response. Mine is
>      C:\Users\Bernard\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART
> 5. Open a new workbook
> 6. Open Excel > File > Options > Formulas > Uncheck ‘ R1C1 reference
>      style’ under Working with style > click on ‘OK’.
> 7. Click on File > Save as > Browse to the XLSTART folder and give the
>      file the name Book.xltx. Press OK

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem of the R1C1 reference style setting is that Excel saves it in templates and/or files. This behavior is unpredictable and differs from version to version. Due to this, sometimes, this setting gets spread like a worm from a single file.

To address the issue, I've written a [small Add-In](https://github.com/Programmierus/excel-no_r1c1) that silently forces A1 reference style for all existing and new workbooks. It contains also a macro requested and is tested on Office 2016 and 2019.

It's also worth mentioning that [Office ADMX templates](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030) have a built-in policy to control R1C1 defaults (User Policies/Administrative Templates/Microsoft Excel 2016/Excel Options/Formulas/R1C1 reference style). It doesn't affect existing files and templates at all, though.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the template has been saved with the R1C1 option. Maybe you can open it, change the option and overwrite the original template?

Comment: Yes, I think the xl template is called personal.xls

Answer (score 0):

As In.Spite mentioned, it's probably a default template issue. If you overwrite the default with one that has the `R1C1 reference` box unchecked, it should remember the setting.

Here's as KB describing where you can find the default template:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924460

Locate the template, open it, untick the `R1C1 reference box, and overwrite the old template.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly applicable, but...

For some of my purposes R1C1 notation is very useful, so I made a macro that toggles it and attached it to a toolbar button:

```
With Application
    If .ReferenceStyle = xlA1 Then
        .ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
    Else
        .ReferenceStyle = xlA1
    End If

End With ' Application
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written an add-in to address this (and related) issues w.r.t. R1C1 addressing.  The add-in can be configured to save all workbooks in a specific format (either R1C1 or A1 mode) and also to force your Excel into the desired addressing mode whenever you open a workbook.  It also provides a button on the ribbon to switch between addressing modes.  It's available from: http://rath.ca/Misc/VBA/Excel/RC_A1_Toggle_v2.zip